# PySide QObject signals not getting received

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

I want to build a wrapper for my API using `QNetworkAccessManager` and the asynchronous fetching with the `get()` method. I create a subclass of `QObject`, pass the parent class into `__init__` and call `super()` and the signal `this_should_emit` never gets received.

```python
# main.py

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from api.initialize.version import GetVersion
from ui_build.main import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # Window Setup
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        get_version = GetVersion(parent=self)
        get_version.this_should_emit.connect(self.verified_connection)

    def verified_connection(self):
        print("verified")
```

```python
# version.py

import json
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QObject, QEventLoop, Signal
from PySide6.QtNetwork import QNetworkRequest, QNetworkAccessManager


class GetVersion(QObject):
    this_should_emit = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GetVersion, self).__init__(parent)
        print(parent)
        loop = QEventLoop()

        manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        manager.finished.connect(self.get_reply)

        reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://localhost:5000/v1/test")))
        reply.finished.connect(loop.exit)
        loop.exec()

        self.this_should_emit.emit()

    def __del__(self):
        print("deleted")

    def get_reply(self, n):
        print('got reply')
        temp = bytes(n.readAll()).decode("utf8")
        temp = json.loads(temp)
        print(temp)
        self.this_should_emit.emit()
```

Comment: What's the point of creating a separate QObject and running an event loop for that? QNetworkAccessManager is *already* asynchronous. Also, since you're using and *starting* that event loop in the `__init__`, you won't get the signal, since you will connect it when the event loop has already finished.

Comment: Is there any other ways I could keep this organized? I'd like to have individual classes representing different endpoints.

Comment: That depends on your requirement. It may be possible that you just need a QNetworkAccessManager subclass for that (which is also a common practice).

Comment: I seriously appreciate you pointing me in the correct direction. The docs for QNetworkAccessManager PySide are in C++ for some reason.

Comment: That is irrelevant, 99.9% of the functions work exactly in the same way, so, even if the docs are targeting C++ devs, they normally work fine on Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my solution wasn't trying to do any trickery with another QEventLoop, but rather making sure the QNetworkAccessManager had access to the QDialog as a parent.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32738564)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a much easier way of doing it.

Since `QNetworkAccessManager` calls are already asynchronous all you need to do is connect to their `finished` signal and process the response.

```
# version.py

import json
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QObject, QEventLoop, Signal
from PySide6.QtNetwork import QNetworkRequest, QNetworkAccessManager
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from api.initialize.version import GetVersion
from ui_build.main import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.get_reply)
        self.manager.get(QNetworkRequest(
            QUrl("http://localhost:5000/v1/test")
        ))

    def get_reply(self, reply):
        if reply.isFinished():
            # do something...


    def verified_connection(self):
        print("verified")
```